# Internal server Error when running Azure Function in the Portal

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have the following function:

```
public static class FunctionCheckEmail
{
    [FunctionName("FunctionCheckEmail")]
    public static IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [Queue("email-message-admin-confirmation", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")]CloudQueue outputQueue,
        ExecutionContext context,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        return new AcceptedResult();
    }
}
```

function.json:

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.26",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ],
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/AzureAppDomainRegistration.dll",
  "entryPoint": "AzureAppDomainRegistration.FunctionCheckEmail.Run"
}
```

host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {}
}
```

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsSendGridApiKey": "XXXX",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "StorageConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=domainregistration;AccountKey=XXXX"
  }
}
```

When I try to call this function here:

[image]

I get `Internal server Error`. What is wrong? I spent half of day for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, it seems that nuget package `WindowsAzure.Storage (verion 9.3.3)` breaks the output binding. So, you could use `ICollector` and `IAsyncCollector` as parameter types for Storage Queue output bindings.

```
[Queue("101functionsqueue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] ICollector<Customer> queueCollector
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/queue-storage#azure-storage-queue-output-binding).

Comment: For now, you do [have to only use 9.3.1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3784).